# The button doesn´t work at the second time

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am making a code in tkinter that when I press a "Start" button the camera turns on and detects the blue color and when I press the "Stop" button the camera turns off. It works the first time, but the second time, it doesn't work. I just read some questions, and it says that I have to use `.place_forget()` to turn off the camera and I used, but when I want the camera to turn on for the second time again it does not work.
Here is my code:

```
def color():
        global video
        video=cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        ret, frame = video.read()
        if ret == True:
            frameHSV = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            mask = cv2.inRange(frameHSV,azulBajo,azulAlto)
            contornos, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            for c in contornos:
                area = cv2.contourArea(c)
                if area > 3000:
                    M = cv2.moments(c)
                    if (M["m00"]==0): M["m00"]=1
                    x = int(M["m10"]/M["m00"])
                    y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
                    cv2.circle(frame, (x,y), 7, (0,255,0), -1)
                    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                    cv2.putText(frame, '{},{}'.format(x,y),(x+10,y), font, 0.75,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                    nuevoContorno = cv2.convexHull(c)
                    cv2.drawContours(frame, [nuevoContorno], 0, (255,0,0), 3)
          
        img=Image.fromarray(frame)
        image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        lblVideo.configure(image=image)
        lblVideo.image=image
        lblVideo.after(1,color)
    
    def quitar():
        global video
        lblVideo.place_forget()
        video.release()

boton2=Button(frame1,width=5, font = ('Arial',14, 'bold'), text='Inciar', bg='yellow',bd=5, command=color)
boton2.place(x=85, y=210)
boton3=Button(frame1,width=5, font = ('Arial',14, 'bold'), text='Parar', bg='yellow',bd=5, command=quitar)
boton3.place(x=290, y=210)
```

Comment: If the Stop button calls `.place_forget()` to hide the Label, then the Start button must call `.place()` on it to make it visible again.

Comment: Thanks! well, i just get another error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__array_interface__' " doy you know something about it?

Comment: That probably is due to you unconditionally using `frame` even if it's not valid (which will happen when you attempt to stop the camera).  Those last five lines of `color()` should probably be indented one more level, so that they're inside the `if ret == True:` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `video = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` inside `color()`.  So you need to create another function which is called by the *"Inciar"* button and create `video` and call `color()` inside this function.

Also the four lines before `lblVideo.after(...)` should be inside the `if` block.

Below is the updated code:

```py
video = None

def color():
    global after_id
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret == True:
        frameHSV = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        mask = cv2.inRange(frameHSV,azulBajo,azulAlto)
        contornos, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for c in contornos:
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            if area > 3000:
                M = cv2.moments(c)
                if (M["m00"]==0): M["m00"]=1
                x = int(M["m10"]/M["m00"])
                y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
                cv2.circle(frame, (x,y), 7, (0,255,0), -1)
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                cv2.putText(frame, '{},{}'.format(x,y),(x+10,y), font, 0.75,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                nuevoContorno = cv2.convexHull(c)
                cv2.drawContours(frame, [nuevoContorno], 0, (255,0,0), 3)

        img=Image.fromarray(frame)
        image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        lblVideo.configure(image=image)
        lblVideo.image=image

    after_id = lblVideo.after(1, color)

def start_capture():
    global video
    if video is None:
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(1) # open the video cam
        lblVideo.place(x=0, y=0) # show the image label
        color()  # start the capture loop

def quitar():
    global video
    lblVideo.after_cancel(after_id)  # cancel the capture loop
    lblVideo.place_forget()
    video.release()
    video = None  # reset variable to None

boton2=Button(frame1,width=5, font = ('Arial',14, 'bold'), text='Inciar',
              bg='yellow',bd=5, command=start_capture)
boton2.place(x=85, y=210)
boton3=Button(frame1,width=5, font = ('Arial',14, 'bold'), text='Parar', 
              bg='yellow',bd=5, command=quitar)
boton3.place(x=290, y=210)
```